# tried to find bootstrap error using aot angular

Tags: angular, aot

I am trying to use aot compiler for the first time and I am following angular.io after rollup I run npm start then this error is occured.

[Error on cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdZTR.png)

And here is my code, importing AppModule and running the app is working fine but no in case of importing AppModuleNgFactory

[Image of my main.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vmFU.png)

**Code of Main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
// import {AppModule} from "./app/app.module";

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

// platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Comment: Please paste code instead of images

Comment: Code is pasted above, kindly review it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import { platformBrowser }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './aot/app/app.module.ngfactory';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```